# Php Date Conversion change

Tags: php, date, strtotime

When I try to insert date like `20-jan-50` by changing

```
date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date))
```

It stores like `20-01-2050`. But the actual date  was `20-01-1950`. After `1980` stores perfect.Like `20-jan-89` was stored as `20-01-1989`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check [**Docs**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). It is clearly noted within that if number of year is specified in a two digit format, the values between `00-69` are mapped to `2000-2069` and `70-99` to `1970-1999`

> Note:
>   If the number of the year is specified in a two digit format, the values between `00-69` are mapped to `2000-2069` and `70-99` to `1970-1999`. See the notes below for possible differences on `32bit` systems (possible dates might end on `2038-01-19 03:14:07`).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

$date="20-jan-50";
$a=date("d-m-y", strtotime($date));
echo $a;

?>
```

write this code.i hope this work.

Comment: store your date which want to convert in $date.because y is for display last 2 later of year & Y is for display Full year

Answer (score 0):

you date format is not compatible with strtotime you must use: Year, month and day:

```
$date = '2050-01-20';
date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```